# How to change a PHP variable depending on a <select> HTML

Tags: php

I'm currently making an auto-signature in PHP & HTML.

The variable 'layout' is the variable I want to change. It contains the structure of the Html signature (Background, logo, Structure).

```
$layout = file_get_contents('./SIG/SAELEN.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$layout1 = file_get_contents('./SIG/GUIL.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

The Structure is supposed to change, depending on this  :

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" id="Name" name="Sender[department]">
   <option value="1">Choix1</option>
   <option value="2">Choix2</option>
   <option value="3">Choix3</option>
   <option value="4">Choix4</option>
   <option value="5">Choix5</option>
   <option value="6">Choix6</option>
</select>
```

I wish to change the `$layout` value depending, on the user Selection  without having to refresh the Page.

Thanks for taking the time to read, I'm looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

Comment: If you want anything to be done without having to "refresh" the page it means that you have to use Javascript.

Comment: Hello, the problem with JS is that if I use the onclick param, I won't be able to change the PHP variable value.

Comment: you can write a javascript function onChange of select and user appropriate php variable you want

Comment: Research on Ajax, and use it in select change event

Comment: You cannot change from JavaScript a PHP variable  without reloading the page because php is executed BEFORE any javascript/Html code, and PHP is on the server side and JavaScript on the client side

Comment: @SagarSainkar I cannot do that, already tried lol

Comment: Just take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-do-i-pass-javascript-variables-to-php

Comment: Can you Please post your JS code that you already tried,

Comment: @VishalParkash I can, i'm just calling   <select class="form-control" id="sel1" id="Name" name="Sender[department]" onChange="Change()">     But since I'm not able to change the Php variable throw JS no point of doing it.     function Change() {
    var dep = document.getElementById("Selection");
    
    if (dep.value == 1) {
        //Change layout value
    }if (dep.value ==2 ) {
        alert("issou2");
        //change layout2value
    }
    
}

Comment: You have to understand that when Javascript runs then PHP has completed running and even if it was magically possible to change a variable on the server from the client it wouldn't change anything because PHP has completed execution. That's basically how the whole internet works. If you do something that doesn't require reloading the page then it is always javascript. How to accomplish your task is a design question. Do you want to put all possible values in the page and select it in JS, or do you provide an endpoint for AJAX requests that executes PHP and provides you with the result, or.....

Comment: "I wish to change the $layout value depending, on the user Selection without having to refresh the Page." ...this requires AJAX. Here's the basic concept: You handle the change event of the select box. Then you send the selected value to the server via AJAX. The Server receives that request, runs some PHP, reads the value, and sends the correct output back. Your JavaScript code receives the output, and then decides how to update the page in response to that output.

Comment: try this 
function Change() 
{ 

 var layout = '<?php echo $layout; ?>';
 var layout1 = '<?php echo $layout1; ?>';

 var dep = document.getElementById("Selection"); 
 if (dep.value == 1) 
 { 
  // use layout as you want
  
 }
 else if (dep.value ==2 ) 
 { 
  // use layout1 as you want
 }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $layout = file_get_contents('./SIG/1.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);


 $layout1 = file_get_contents('./SIG/2.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
   $layout2 = file_get_contents('./SIG/3.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
   $layout3 = file_get_contents('./SIG/4.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);


if(isset($_POST['select']))

{
    if($_POST['select'] == 'value2')
    {
        $layout = $layout1;

    }
    if($_POST['select'] == 'value3') {
    $layout = $layout2;
    }

    if($_POST['select'] == 'value4') {
    $layout = $layout3;
                                     }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

There is no possibility to change php variable without refreshing the page. But as per your requirement you can use techniques to achieve your goal. I suggest below solution for this using ajax call.

index.php

```
 <?php?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sel1').change(function(){
                var getValue = $(this).val();
               // alert(getValue);
                //Ajax call
                $.post('do.php', { selectedValue: getValue }, function(data){
                    //alert('check response value:  '+data);
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" id="Name" name="Sender[department]">
       <option value="1">Choix1</option>
       <option value="2">Choix2</option>
       <option value="3">Choix3</option>
       <option value="4">Choix4</option>
       <option value="5">Choix5</option>
       <option value="6">Choix6</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

do.php

```
<?php
// get posted value
if ($_POST['selectedValue']){ 
     //echo "posted--". $_POST['selectedValue'];
    // do your logic here
    //$layout = file_get_contents('./SIG/SAELEN.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    //$layout1 = file_get_contents('./SIG/GUIL.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
}
?>
```

I hope you can get an idea by using this way.

Answer (score 1):

> we cannot change PHP variable from javascript. Php is backend and js
>   is frontend.

Solution is to call a ajax call when ever user changes the select input

or

you can store both layouts in two js variables and use them when user changes the select input